# How to dealing with multy source Database using DbContext

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, domain-driven-design, ardalis-cleanarchitecture

I used clean arch steps to create the project,
but the problem that i have more then three aggregate that i need to put them in referents Database.

I tried to use DbContext for each aggregate like this:

```
public class AppDbContext : DbContext
{
  private readonly IMediator? _mediator;

  public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options, IMediator? mediator)
      : base(options)
  {
    _mediator = mediator;
  }
.
.
.
public class AnalyzeDbContext : DbContext
{
  private readonly IMediator? _mediator;

  public AnalyzeDbContext(DbContextOptions<AnalyzeDbContext> options, IMediator? mediator)
      : base(options)
  {
    _mediator = mediator;
  }
.
.
.
public class ProviderMgrDbContext : DbContext
{
  private readonly IMediator? _mediator;


  public ProviderMgrDbContext(DbContextOptions<ProviderMgrDbContext> options, IMediator? mediator)
      : base(options)
  {
    _mediator = mediator;
  }
```

And i send the connection string for each DbContext like this:

```
//#Update 1
 public static void AppDbContext(this IServiceCollection services, string connectionString) =>
   services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options => options.UseMySQL(connectionString));

 public static void ProviderMgrDbContext(this IServiceCollection services, string connectionString) =>
   services.AddDbContext<ProviderMgrDbContext>(options => options.UseMySQL(connectionString));

  public static void AnalyzeDbContext(this IServiceCollection services, string connectionString) =>
   services.AddDbContext<AnalyzeDbContext>(options => options.UseMySQL(connectionString));

//#After
public static void AppDbContext(this IServiceCollection services, string connectionString) =>
   services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options => options.UseMySql(connectionString, new MySqlServerVersion(new Version(8, 0, 27))));

 public static void ProviderMgrDbContext(this IServiceCollection services, string connectionString) =>
   services.AddDbContext<ProviderMgrDbContext>(options => options.UseMySql(connectionString, new MySqlServerVersion(new Version(8, 0, 27))));
  
  public static void AnalyzeDbContext(this IServiceCollection services, string connectionString) =>
   services.AddDbContext<AnalyzeDbContext>(options => options.UseMySql(connectionString, new MySqlServerVersion(new Version(8, 0, 27))));
.
.
.
```

But when i try to migrate them it's show exemption error like this:

```
PM> Add-Migration init_1 -context AppDbContext
Build started...
Build succeeded.
Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException: An exception was thrown while activating WetaPayment.Infrastructure.Data.DataContext.AppDbContext.
 ---> Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException: An exception was thrown while invoking the constructor 'Void .ctor(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions`1[WetaPayment.Infrastructure.Data.DataContext.AppDbContext], MediatR.IMediator)' on type 'AppDbContext'.
 ---> System.TypeLoadException: Method 'AppendIdentityWhereCondition' in type 'MySql.EntityFrameworkCore.MySQLUpdateSqlGenerator' from assembly 'MySql.EntityFrameworkCore, Version=5.0.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d' does not have an implementation.
```

Finally I fixed part of the problem with change `MySql.EntityFrameworkCore` package that was not compatible with net6.0 so i used `Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql` and it's worked successfully.

**But still i have another problem that is my all aggregate balded in all context, and i need each DbContext build only his aggregate, so how to fix it ?**

Comment: 9 out of 10 times I see a `TypeLoadException` in EF Core it's because I'm using incompatible versions of the EF Core packages, make sure all your references to EF Core across all you projects reference the same versions

Comment: Dear MindSwipe I checked my  EF versions and it's all the latest versions, i used net6.0.

Comment: MindSwipe uoy are right,
finally I find the problem with my `MySql.EntityFrameworkCore` backage that was not compatable with net6.0 so i used `Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql` and it's worked.

Comment: Now I have another problem, my all aggregate balded in all context, and i need each DbContext build only his aggregate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each `DbContext` can config their own entity

Let assume we have 10 entities for 3 `DbContext`, we can separate them out 2 entities for `ADbContext`, 5 for `BDbContext` and 3 for `CDbContext`. Manage the configuration like `FK`, between them wisely, otherwise, that would turn to be chaos. Here is how to doing this, using fluent API

```
public class MyAppDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<OurEntity> OurEntity { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Entity<OurEntity>(builder => 
       {
            // Our implementation goes here...
       });
    }
}
```

Like that, we config and register only entities correspondingly with each `DbContext`.

We need to register each `DbContext` separately to whatever kind of DI

Organize Migration operation for each `DbContext`

I usually organize them in folder like this:

```
Data/Migrations/ContextA
Data/Migrations/ContextB
Data/Migrations/ContextC
```

Each context have their own Migrations and snapshot.

Doing this by specify separate `DbContext` when using `EF` migration tool

```
add-migration add [MigrationName] -context [DbContextName] -o [Path to desire place to store migration]
```

then apply them separately by

```
update-database -context [DbContextName]
```